# JavaScript trying to access child of div then change css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Oke, so I am trying to create an interactive menu.
Now I am really struggling to make the JavaScript access the child nodes of a div and change a specific css element.

The html code goes as follow:

```
<div id="navbar">
        Control panel
        <div class="button" onclick="openMe(self);">
            Users
            <div class="sub-button">
                Profile
            </div>
            <div class="sub-button">
                Ban
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="button">
            Roles
            <div class="sub-button">
                Profile
            </div>
            <div class="sub-button">
                Ban
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the JavaScript is :

```
function openMe(a)
{
        child = a.document.getElementsByClassName('sub-button');
        console.log("a is "+a);
        console.log("child is "+$(child).get());
        console.log(self);
        for (i = 0; i < child.length; i++){
            //
            console.log("Key "+i+" is "+child[i]);
            console.log("Display for "+i+" is "+child[i].style.display);
            if (child[i].style.display == "" || child[i].style.display == "none"){
                child[i].style.display = "block";
            } else {
                child[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```

In the css sub-button is hidden.
Now I have been trying to google, but I haven't found anything even close.

How can I make it that if I press button, the sub-buttons within button change css elements?

gr,
Angels

edit :
jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r7tzr6dm/

Comment: It will much easier to help if you provide a JSFiddle

Comment: Have you taken a look into the error console? Proberbly an error message did orccur. Are you sure that them method `document.getElementsByClassName()` does work or gives a result?

Comment: Yes it works and returns:
[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: @jiacheo I use `jQuery` myself. A lot. But your comment isn't pertinent. If the OP is using a library, they would mention it.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I do have it included but I just try to get it working with or without hence it seemed like a not that important thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the first line. When you would open the error console, a error message will occur.
Change the line `a.document.getElementsByClassName('sub-button');` to `a.getElementsByClassName('sub-button');`.

The second error is change `onclick="openMe(self);` to `onclick="openMe(this);`.

Comment: actually it errors when I remove the document part,
"TypeError: a.getElementsByClassName is not a function"

Comment: I tried it on my local computer and at my jsfiddle. your code works, after removing `.document`.

Comment: That's weird, how come I get an error but you don't? :/
Really trying to solve this but it got my head twisted

Comment: Can you tell me how it comes that I failed but your code works? Is the "self" faulty or something? Thanks very much though! :)

Comment: @AngelsDustz I did oversee the second change. Sorry.